# How to get minimum item from a dict of lists?

Tags: python, dictionary

My dictionary looks like this:

```
Key:                List:
AB                   [A, B, 32]
AC                   [A, C, 20]
AD                   [A, D, 18]
```

I want to get the key that has the minimum value in the third location on the list. So, `AD` is what I want outputted.

The code I am using is:

```
print min(dict.keys(), key=lambda x: x[2])
```

Comment: What's the problem with your code?

Comment: @MarkusMeskanen it tells me that the min arg is an empty sequence

Comment: `min(d, key=lambda x: d[x][-1])`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You almost had it. You're iterating over the keys, so `x` is the key you'll use to index into your dictionary. This is what you want:

```
In [797]: min(d, key=lambda x: d[x][-1])
Out[797]: 'AD'
```

I would also recommend renaming your dictionary to something besides `dict`, it shadows the builtin class `dict`.